# Android - Fixing European Currency Input which Uses Commas instead of Decimals

Tags: android, decimal, currency, euro

Firstly, I know Doubles aren't the best for currency, but in this case, precision is not profoundly important. So, I have a live app in the Play store and I found a problem with Euro currencies. For some reason, if a Euro localization is used (can't reproduce this with ADB localizations) users can enter a comma in a numberDecimal EditText to delimit the dollars and cents. So, when you're expecting to get "1000.00" from a user in North America, you may get "1000,00" from someone in Norway.

This being said, is it typical that numberDecimal localizes like this and allows for the comma? If so, do you know if it limits users to inserting just the last comma? I am asking as I am using the following code to fix this problem, as you can see, it relies on their being just a single comma to replace:

```
 // Required to handle European use of commas instead of decimals places
    // in their currency.
    edittext_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable edittext_amount) {
            String amount = "";
            if (edittext_amount != null) {
                try {
                    amount = edittext_amount.toString().replace(",", ".");
                    double_edittext_amount = Double.parseDouble(amount);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Error
                }
            }

        }
```

As mentioned, the above code was instituted to prevent the comma from creating an error, the error I receive is as follows:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1000,00"
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
at com.ootpapps.saving.made.simple.SavingsPlanEditor.validateSavingsPlan(SavingsPlanEditor.java:233)
at com.ootpapps.saving.made.simple.SavingsPlanEditor.access$1(SavingsPlanEditor.java:217)
at com.ootpapps.saving.made.simple.SavingsPlanEditor$2.onClick(SavingsPlanEditor.java:109)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you for your insight, I hope to settle this once and for all!

Edit - Changed the code to use NumberFormat, as follows:

```
// Required to handle European use of commas instead of decimals places
    // in their currency.
    edittext_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable edittext_amount) {
            String amount = "";
            if (edittext_amount != null) {
                try {
                    amount = edittext_amount.toString();

                    NumberFormat number_format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                    double_edittext_amount = number_format.parse(amount).doubleValue();

                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Error
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try using [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) perhaps.

Comment: You can obtain the number format defined by the users Locale by calling `#getNumberInstance()` - it can be used to format and parse numbers according to the current device settings - i.e. Norwegians will get 1000,0 and Americans 1000.0.

Comment: Thanks, it was really easy to just use getNumberInstance() as you say, really simple. Posting amended code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way to do what you are doing;

```
String amount = null;
String fist = null;
String second = null;
if (edittext != null){
    amount = edittext.to string();
    if (amount.contains(","){
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, ",");
         first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain the whole number
         second = tokens.nextToken();//this will contain the decimal part
    } else if (amount.contains("."){
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, ".");
        first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain the whole number
        second = tokens.nextToken();//this will contain the decimal part
    }//That bit removed the decimal points, from the strings, now we just put them back together
String fullNumber = first + "." + second;
double_edittext_amount = Double.parseDouble(fullNumber);
```

Hope this helps